# No provider for App Error ,Ionic 3 in StackBlitz

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm getting a `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for App!` in my console even after adding **App** in providers in **StackBlitz**.

[Here is my Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-scrolling-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error was due to importing **App** from 
`import { App } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/app';`

After changing this to 
`import { App } from 'ionic-angular';`

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

-> in `app.module.ts` remove "App" from providers in `app.module.ts`

-> App is not a service so you can remove "App" in providers and it works.

Comment: actually due to the error I added App to providers .

Answer (score 1):

You should remove App from Providers from your app.modules.ts file. 
Actually, Providers is just used for add services which you are using into your application.

Comment: actually due to the error I added App to providers .

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove

```
import { App } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/app';
```

this line from your `scrolling.header.directive.ts` file and modify below mentioned line in same file from

```
import { Platform,  DomController} from 'ionic-angular';
```

to

```
import { Platform,  DomController, App } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Comment: You can approve this answer if it has resolved your issue.

Comment: can you add some details also like why it is so?

Comment: It is because you have already added the dependency of App in your app.module.ts file so you do not need to add it again in your directive.

Comment: no actually its not even needed in the app.module.ts .And what is the difference between `import { App } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/app';` and `import { Platform,  DomController, App } from 'ionic-angular';`.